# How I can bind the result set to gridview by binding all properties of the first class and some properties of other class

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, linq-to-sql

I have Two class `StudentMaster` and `StudentMark` the first have 30 properties 
and the second have 20 properties. 
I want linq query with return all properties from `StudentMaster` 
and 2 properties from  `StudentMark`.

I have tried following code :

```
        var objStudLst =
            (from sm in dc.StudentMasters
             join mar in dc.StudentMarks on sm.SID equals mar.SID
             select new { sm, mar.Subjects, mar.Marks }).ToList();

            GridView1.DataSource = objStudLst;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

And my aspx page code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>
```

Here problem is the gridview only display two column **subject** and **mark**.
There are no binding done for any of the property of class `StudentMaster` while I want to bind all 30 properties of `StudentMaster` with this grid view.

Comment: As you have so many properties to handle, the better way to go, you should join in SQL script, create it as **Stored Procedures** or use **dc.ExecuteQuery** instead of join in linQ query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your LINQ explicitly state the `sm` properties, like this:

```
var objStudLst =
        (from sm in dc.StudentMasters
         join mar in dc.StudentMarks on sm.SID equals mar.SID
         select new { mar.Subjects, 
                      mar.Marks, 
                      sm.Property1, 
                      sm.Property2, etc. }).ToList();
```

Comment: yes this the way but it is too lengthy to write all 30 properties in the select list. Is there any other way to do so.

Comment: @BhaveshKachhadiya as has been suggested, why not create an SP and just bind the results to the grid?

Comment: @Ric Because this type of things I need to do at many places, so I don't think to create SP for all this requirement.